# Configure NavigationView to show text-only menu, without showing icon-only rail

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Is there a way to configure NavigationView so that I don't need waste time setting up Icons?

All I want is a hamburger button that opens like a start menu with a generic bullet icon, and then closes all the way back to a hamburger button once an item is selected regardless of window size.  I don't want the navigation menu to ever convert to an icon-only rail on the side.

Basically, I need to jam the NavigationView's DisplayMode to remain in "Minimal" Mode regardless of the window size.  Minimal mode is defined as "Only the hamburger button remains fixed while the pane shows and hides as needed." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationviewdisplaymode)

(Just the usual problem that none of the icons fit the menu headings or combinations of "noun and verb" of the menu item...icons tend to be either all verbs or all nouns, not subtle combinations of the both "verb and noun"...thus, the need to avoid icons in navigation menuitems...)

Any ideas how to configure this?

```
<NavigationView 
 ???Set Property: Don't Open Icon-Only Rail Ever Regardless of Size???>
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
       <NavigationViewItem Icon="SolidStar" Content="MenuItem1"/>
       <NavigationViewItem Icon="SolidStar" Content="MenuItem2"/>
       <NavigationViewItem Icon="SolidStar" Content="MenuItem3"/>
       <NavigationViewItem Icon="SolidStar" Content="MenuItem4"/>
       <NavigationViewItem Icon="SolidStar" Content="MenuItem5"/>
       <NavigationViewItem Icon="SolidStar" Content="MenuItem6"/>
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>

    <Frame Name="A1Frame" />
</NavigationView>
```

Comment: thought about that already... docs says its a readonly property...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.displaymode#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_NavigationView_DisplayMode    It has a threshold for switching to compat mode, I suppose I could set it to the screen size so that it never switches...but that seems like a hack because you can make a window larger than the screen size with virtual screens...  if they had opinion for setting theshold to -1 meaning threshhold is infinite that would work...

Answer (score 1):

Try this and adjust the values according to your needs.

```
<NavigationView CompactModeThresholdWidth="1920" ExpandedModeThresholdWidth="1920"/>
```

Detailed explanation can be found [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview#overriding-the-default-adaptive-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest an alternative for people who don't want waste time with Icons to instead embrace the concept of a "Font Letter" as an Icon.  Then you can reuse the icons as a keyboard shortcut as well.  (I'm sure there's probably a nice font out there somewhere as an alternative to the "Consolas" font that puts a nice circle around each letter...to give it a button appearance.)  Example:

```
<NavigationView>

<NavigationvViewItem Tag="EvilPlan" Content="(E)dit Master Plan">
   <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
       <FontIcon FontFamily="Consolas" Glyph="E"/>
   </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
</NavigationViewItem>

<NavigationViewItem Tag="Coffee" Content="Make (C)offee">
   <NavigationViewiItem.Icon>
       <FontIcon FontFamily="Consolas" Glyph="C"/>
   </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
</NavigationViewItem>

<NavigationViewItem Tag="Nifty" Content="Do Something (N)ifty">
   <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
       <FontIcon FontFamily="Consolas" Glyph="N"/>
   </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
</NavigationViewItem>


<!-- Also Just Noticed that Microsoft Even let's you put 
       upto 3 letters in the Font Glyph -->
<NavigationViewItem Tag="Nifty" Content="Make (S)ound">
   <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
       <FontIcon FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize= Glyph="BAM"/>
   </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
</NavigationViewItem>


</NavigationView>
```